# Search for multiple documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, is there a way I can search for multiple items at once? For example, I have a Products collection. I want to return an array of objects products where `product_code = 1000, 2000. 3000`.

My semi-pseudocode query would be something like:

`Products.find({product_code: [1000, 2000, 3000]});`

The desired output would be something like:

```
[
    {
        "_id":"1",
        "product_code":"1000",
        "price":"300"
    },
    {
        "_id":"2",
        "product_code":"2000",
        "price":"500"
    },
    {
        "_id":"3",
        "product_code":"3000",
        "price":"400"
    }
]
```

I couldn't find anything relating to this in the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator to find documents where a field contains any value in the array:

```js
Products.find({product_code: {$in: ['1000', '2000', '3000']}});
```